# 2010 Elantra Touring - LED dashboard display is flickering

Tags: elantra, dashboard, led, i30

This problem started two weeks ago. When I start my car, the LED display on my dashboard flickers and is dim. After I drive it a while (5-10 minutes) the LED becomes stable and bright. My local mechanic has replaced the alternator, tested the battery, cleaned my dimmer switch and cleaned the contacts in the instrument panel. Any suggestions would be appreciated. See video link:

[The flickering LED dashboard](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMQTJ6VLm4XcfmkhG__j6B_Lk4pg7FiT8K5ZBeGwqE1FvOR5jsBn8QiMXdemMLx8g?key=QmdVdUJiR0FNcVJabXZkVjQ4U1JoMlQ4Y295Y0Zn) video

Comment: I think you need more data. Dim lights can be a sign of low voltage but there could be other things. An important test is measure your battery voltage before and after starting.

Comment: Did he replace the alternator as a guess, or was it faulty?

Comment: Does it flicker before you start the engine?